# Proof that ideals of Dedekind domains are generated by at most two elements: how does the bolded step in the proof work?

Tags: commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

Sorry for the slightly obscure title, but I could not think of a better way to word it. The lecture notes for my commutative algebra course have the following proof that Dedekind domains' ideals are always generated by at most two elements, but there is one step in the proof that neither I nor anyone else I've asked can make any sense of. I've asked people good enough at this that I'm convinced it's at least not blindingly obvious.

**Proof.** Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Let $a\in I\setminus\{0\}$, and let $J = Ra$. We can factorise $J$ as $\prod_{i=1}^m P_i^{s_i}$ for some prime ideals $P_i$ and $s_i\in \mathbb{N}$. Since $J\subseteq I$, we must have $I = \prod_{i=1}^mP_i^{n_i}$ for some integers $0\leq n_i \leq s_i$.

We have $I/J \cong \prod_{i=1}^m P_i^{n_i}/P_i^{s_i}$ by the Chinese remainder theorem. **Let us choose $b_i\in P_i\setminus P_i^2$. This gives $Rb_i^{n_i} + P_i^{s_i} = P_i^{n_i}$** and so each $P_i^{n_i}/P_i^{s_i}$ is a principal ideal in $R/P_I^{s_i}$. Hence $I/J$ is a principal ideal generated say by $b+J$ in the ring $R/J$. Then $I = Rb + J = \langle a, b \rangle$. $\quad\square$

Any help on parsing this proof would be greatly appreciated by me and several others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P^s\subseteq b^nR+P^s\subseteq P^n$$ so the prime factorization of $b^nR+P^s$ is $P^k$ for some $k$. Now $$b^nR+P^s\not \subseteq P^{n+1}$$ as $$b^{n}\not \in P^{n+1}$$ so we can only have $k=n$.

Comment: The last step looks very plausible, and in fact was the part we were getting hung up on, to the point where we decided this couldn't be the right path. You've given a bit more plausibility to it but ... why can $b^n$ not be in $P^{n+1}$? The ideal is generated by products, but does not merely consist of products. I am feeling more that this might just be a case of mass confusion because this does feel like it should be simple.

Comment: @Nethesis Well, at this point, I think you have the prime factorization theorem. OK, so $(b)=PQ$ where $Q$ is an ideal, prime to $P$, this means that $(b^n)=P^nQ^n$. If $b^n\in P^{n+1}$ then $(b^n)=P^{n+1}R$ for some $R$ not divisible by $P$. This contradicts unique factorization. Of course there are other ways to solve this problem, I gave this method not because I think its best but cause I thought is was closest to what you were thinking about.

Comment: In fact $P^n=(b^n)+P^{n+1}$

Comment: Thank makes sense, thank you very much!